# Data aggregation in JavaScript, Arrays (Multiple API requests)

Tags: javascript, dictionary, multidimensional-array, reduce

I need to merge a series of API requests that all have the same shape data. The data is returned in the form of a series of arrays's within an array, with an epoch value and the raw data point value:

```
    let response1 = [
        [1610496000000, 24294673600.944046],
        [1610582400000, 24337321169.826145],
        [1610668800000, 24213693580.926777],
        [1610755200000, 24266793529.261494],
        [1610841600000, 24315907744.20519],
        [1610928000000, 24325253500.348637],
        [1611014400000, 24361784336.09795],
        [1611025732000, 24322220360.696705],
    ]

    let response2 = [
        [1610496000000, 4783652038.103683],
        [1610582400000, 4762603311.208288],
        [1610668800000, 4828960535.356582],
        [1610755200000, 4876847232.563923],
        [1610841600000, 5042504749.588362],
        [1610928000000, 5073254051.47403],
        [1611014400000, 5130649762.345672],
        [1611028765000, 5125428823.791457],
    ]
```

The goal is to be able to sum each unique epoch value into one value.

It is safe to assume that each dataset will return the same number of items (and the same epochs), although I would be interested in an elegant solution to handle if each dataset does not contain an epoch that the other data sets do.

I was trying to work with combining `.reduce` and `.map` but I am hitting a brick wall.

Comment: So you want the result to be sum of the elements from respose1 and response2? 

result[0] = response1[0] + response2[0]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create an empty dictionary
2. Iterate on the outer array
3. In each outer array iteration, iterate on the inner array.
4. In each sub iteration check if the timestamp exists as a key in the dictionary. If it doesn't, add it and set its associated value as the value of that dictionary entry. If it does exist, add its associated value to the dictionary entry's current value.

```html
const sumDict = {};
response.forEach((batch) => {
  batch.forEach((datapoint) => {
    const [key, value] = datapoint;
    if (!sumDict[key]) {
      sumDict[key] = value;
    } else {
      sumDict[key] += value;
    }
  });
});
```

Note: in your example, you need to wrap your response array with another set of brackets.